# Comparing two columns and keeping NaNs

Tags: python, pandas

My data has the structure of `c1` and `c2` and I want to generate `c3`

```
 c1  c2    c3
  x   x  True
NaN   y   NaN
  x NaN   NaN
  y   x False
```

My approach generates the wanted result but is extremely slow:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'c1': ['x', np.nan,'x','y'],
    'c2': ['x', 'y',np.nan,'x'],
})

df['c3'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['c1'] == row['c2'] if type(row['c1']) is str and type(row['c2']) is str else np.nan, axis=1)
```

My approach is extremely slow as my dataset has 100k+ rows and this process is done for multiple column pairs

Is there a more efficient or elegant way of achieving the same result.
I am using pandas 0.24.1

Comment: What you mean `multiple columns`? You will compare more than two at a time? Or you will always compare twp columns at a time, but  with many different combinations ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution using `np.select`

```
cond2 = df['c1'] == df['c2']
cond1 = (df['c1'].isnull()) | (df['c2'].isnull())

df['c3'] = np.select([cond1, cond2], [None, True], False)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  c1   c2     c3                                                                                                                    
0    x    x   True                                                                                                                    
1  NaN    y   None                                                                                                                    
2    x  NaN   None                                                                                                                    
3    y    x  False
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need `apply` here using `nunique` check one have one unique value , using `isnull` + `any` `mask` the `NaN` row to `NaN`

```
(df.nunique(1)==1).astype(object).mask(df.isnull().any(1))
Out[61]: 
0     True
1      NaN
2      NaN
3    False
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

`df['c3'] = (df.c1==df.c2)`

`df.loc[df.isnull().any(1), 'c3'] = np.nan`